# ajc via cmd line doesn't recognize .aj aspect syntax

Tags: java, aspectj

when trying to compile an aspect file using ajc and the command line, im getting error when trying to compile `*.aj` file (aspect syntax)

It works fine when compiling `*.java` aspect (using annotations)

Aspect Annotation - `TestAspect.java`:

```
@Aspect
public class TestAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* TestTarget.test(..))")
    void test() {} 

    @Before("test()")
    public void advice(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.printf("TestAspect.advice() called on '%s'%n", joinPoint);

    }
}
```

Aspect Syntax - `TestAspect.aj`:

```
    public aspect TestAspect {

        pointcut test() : execution(* TestTarget.test*(...));

        before() : test()
        public void advice(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
            System.out.printf("TestAspect.advice() called on '%s'%n", joinPoint);
        }
}
```

when compiling TestAspect.aj im using the following command:

```
ajc -1.8 -sourceroots ./ -cp aspectjrt.jar;
```

and getting the following errors:

```
C:\****\TestAspect.aj:3 [error] Syntax error on token "...", "name pattern" expected
pointcut test() : execution(* TestTarget.test*(...));
                                               ^
C:\****\TestAspect.aj:6 [error] Syntax error on token "public", "{" expected
public void advice(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
^
C:\****\TestAspect.aj:7 [error] joinPoint cannot be resolved to a variable
System.out.printf("TestAspect.advice() called on '%s'%n", joinPoint);


3 errors
```

I didn't manage to find any solution while googling for over an hour.
even not in the documentation.

I might be missing something, will be glad for some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution:

```
public aspect TestAspect {

    pointcut test() : execution(* TestTarget.test*(..));

    before() : test() {
        System.out.printf("TestAspect.advice() called on '%s'%n", thisJoinPoint);
    }
}
```

1) notice the `test()` argument wildcard is only 2 dots instead of 3!

2) advice body doesn't have a method signature and you can reference thisJoinPoint without passing it as a parameter

(note im talking about the `*.aj` file)

Comment: Try accepting your own answer in order to close the question. Or delete it altogether.